# AWS crashed if my sites are taking too much space?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Just have a small question.

Can AWS be crashed if one of the sites is taking too much space?

As an example, let's say if one site is creating daily backups and those backups reach multiple GBs, would it be possible that AWS would crash the whole server making all sites go down?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about an EC2 instance, yes, if you run out of disk space it can cause problem, including crashing your website - I have done it for a site that needed temporary files created on page load (not all sites do, this was an asp.net application).

But to be clearer, at most it only crashes your website(s) on your single server - it doesn't crash 'AWS' or anyone else's systems running on another instance. If you are running 10 websites on your instance, and you fill the disk on that instance, you *could* cause all 10 of your websites to fail until you free up space.